# Limit the number of characters displayed from mysql in coldfusion

Tags: mysql, coldfusion

I have a MySql database which is being displayed via Coldfusion, the code to query the database is:

```
<cfquery name="GetWp_posts" datasource="#session.odbcname#">
SELECT  post_content
FROM    wp_posts
ORDER by ID desc
LIMIT 0, 2 </cfquery>
```

The code that displays the results is:

```
<cfoutput query="getWp_posts">
            <cfif trim(getWp_posts.post_content) is not ""><div class = "courseShortDesc">#getWp_posts.post_content#</div></cfif>
        </cfoutput>
```

How do I limit the amount of characters displayed in the results?

Many Thanks

Answer (score 5):

You want the `Left` function

```
#Left(getWp_posts.post_content, 20)#
```

http://help.adobe.com/en_US/ColdFusion/9.0/CFMLRef/WSc3ff6d0ea77859461172e0811cbec22c24-6e3a.html

There is also a MySQL function called `SUBSTRING` that can produce similar results.

http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/string-functions.html#function_substring

Comment: If you can, check the question answered.

Comment: You may also want to take a look at http://cflib.org/udf/FullLeft on CFLib.  It is an enhanced left() that doesn't cut off words, if that is what you need.